# select2 4.0.8, templateSelection option not working

Tags: ajax, angular, jquery-select2

I am using `select2` version `4.0.8` with ajax search. In my angular 4 application with ajax call. Till searching and populating result it works fine. But after that when I click on any option  it doesn't call method specified in `templateSelection` option.

Below is the code I am using:

```
jQuery(".suggestion"+i).select2({
  placeholder: 'Select Countries',
  ajax: {
    url: AppConstants.facebookBaseUrl + "/search",
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    type: "GET",
    beforeSend: (request)=> {
      request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+this.user.facebookPage_Token);
    },
    data: (params)=> {
      return {
        q: params.term, // search term
        location_types: this.facebookFilters[i].filter,
        type: "adgeolocation",
        page: params.page
      };
    },
    processResults: function (data, params) {

      // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
      // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
      // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
      // scrolling can be used
      params.page = params.page || 1;

      return {
        results: data.data,
        pagination: {
          more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
        }
      };
    },
    cache: true
  },
  multiple:true,
  minimumInputLength: 2,
  templateResult: formatRepo,
  templateSelection: formatRepoSelection
});

function formatRepo (repo) {
  if (repo.loading) {
    return repo.text;
  }      
  var $container = jQuery("<option (click)='selectCountry($event)' class='country_name' value='"+repo.key+"'>"+repo.name+"</option>");
  return $container;
}

function formatRepoSelection (repo) {
  var $container = jQuery("<option class='selectedCountry' value='"+repo.key+"'>"+repo.name+"</option>");
  return $container;
  // return repo.key || repo.text;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" name="selected[]" [ngClass]="'suggestion'+i"></select>
```

What I am doing wrong here?
thanks in advance!

Comment: For Future reference: You may be missing a parameter `id` in the ajax response. The response should contain a unique variable `id`.

Comment: Did you ever solve it? Having the same issue (v4.1rc). The `templateSelection` function just isn't begin called. Actually, it is called once, and the returned string is displayed on the selector before selecting anything...

Comment: And, as could've been expected... I solved just after typing the above comment. At least in 4.1, there's now a `templateResult` option that does the expected. Which I now also see that you've used... so in my case it was simply negligence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by changing `option` to `span` as:

```
function formatRepoSelection (repo) {
  var $container = jQuery("<span class='selectedCountry'>"+repo.name+"</span>");
  return $container;
  // return repo.key || repo.text;
}
```

Comment: No Change at all. Results are getting populated properly, but after that it doesn't work. I mean when I click on options which are present in form of `li` do not work.

Comment: @JayeshChoudhary can you create stackblitz with your code?

Comment: Hi, Plz find details over here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kggcsp Also I need multiselect.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I did not have the id and text properties in my dataset, once added, I was able to see the selection highlight when hovering over an item and returning a result when selected:

```
    {
      "results": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "text": "Option 1"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "text": "Option 2",
        "selected": true
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "text": "Option 3",
        "disabled": true
      }]
    }
```